# Adding StackView containing a large number of ImageViews to ScrollView takes very long in Xamarin.Forms.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms.iOS app, I want to scroll images one by one vertically in a ScrollView, like a PDF viewer. I added 1500 ImageViews to a StackView. And then added this StackView as a Subview to a ScrollView. All these operations are performed asynchronous. When I launch my app, the images appear only after 7 minutes. I debugged the code and found that the line ScrollView.addSubview(StackView) takes very long to execute, although adding the 1500 ImageViews to StackView is quick. And the length of time takes is directly proportional to the number of ImageViews. A workable solution will be very helpful. Thanks!